# Limit of a sequence of integrals implies pointwise limit of a sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions

Pointwise limit of a sequence of functions

Let $f$, $f_{n}\in C[0, 1]$ for all $n\geq 1$. Suppose that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int^{1}_{0}|f_{n}(t)-f(t)|dt=0.
$$
Is it possible to show that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}|f_{n}(t)-f(t)|=0,
$$
for all $t\in [0, 1]$?

Comment: no, try $f_n(x)=x^n$

Comment: No, because it won't hold in general. You even have sequence that converges in $L^1$ and such that $\lim_{n\to \infty }f_n(x)=f(x)$ will hold for no $x$.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by [Surb](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/154545/surb), you can even have cases were $\lim_{n\to \infty }f_n(x)=f(x)$ will hold for no $x \in [0,1]$. The idea is to have a bump getting thinner and sliding back and forth between $0$ and $1$.

See [here](https://www.mathcounterexamples.net/counterexamples-around-dominated-convergence-theorem/) for a detailed example.

Comment: However there is a subsequence wich converges pointwise almost everywhere.

Comment: @Ruy Indeed. This is part of integration beauties!